# display base64 encoded office files in electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, base64, data-uri

I have some document that are presented as data uri `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document...` and I would like to display them to the user. If this is not possible the other option is to extract the mime type from the data uri and then zip each single file using jszip to let the user download them.

Is there any possibility to display `.docx, .doc, .txt` or documents like `.xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx` in an html page?

Comment: Why not using the fact that document have their default program (open with...) declared and simply send an ipc to the main and in the main use  shell.openItem(yourFilefPath)

Comment: I'm a newbie with electron so I didn't know about this possibility. Also I want to give a preview of the file but I will try as you've suggested, but I don't know if the document in dataURI can be sent to the related program directly?

Comment: Sorry I thought (or understand) the document where local......